# How can my father stay with me in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, family, eu-citizens, uk-residents

I have an Italian nationality and came to England in March 2016 where I live and work.

Today, my father arrived in England. He did not need a visa but entered with his residence card of a family member of a union citizen. At Immigration, the officer put a stamp on my father's passport and it shows just the date.

What do we have to do next for him to stay with me? Do we have to apply for a visa or a residence card?

Comment: Assuming that your father wishes to stay with you and not just visit, please ask this on our [Expatriates site](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com), which deals with living and working in another country.

Comment: If he is he not planning to stay for longer than 3 months then the question belongs here (and the answer is "nothing"); if he wants to stay for longer than 3 months then the question belongs there (and the answer is "you don't have to, but you may want to").  If you ask on [Expatriates.SE], you should also mention whether you are hoping to remain in the UK after it leaves the EU.  The UK will also re-examine whether your father continues to be dependent on you, so if there's likely to be any question about that, you should discuss the circumstances in your question.